# App crashes on button press signal:Sigbart

Tags: swift

I'm trying to build city guide app from template but I'm unable to switch from sections view to just map view. As I understand this error means that code isn't quite finished and its missing something. Would gladly appreciate if anyone could help me with this one.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUCMO.png

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code - post your code as text here.

Comment: Read the error in the debugger console. It's pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

As the debugger console has indicated that:

**You're trying to cast value of type `appyCity.SelectionsViewController` to `appyCity.MapPoiViewController`. It's impossible => Crash**

If you're not sure about the value of a property, let's use the `Optional Chaining` and `Optional Binding` instead of `Forced Unwrapping` To minimize the possibility of a crash.

Your code should look like this:

```
if let MPVC = segue.destination as? MapPoiViewController {
    // MPVC is MapPoiViewController type
} else {
    // MPVC isn't MapPoiViewController type
}
```

See more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

Hope this helps you!